# fail() handler also fires on HTTP200 and HTTP202

Tags: javascript, jquery, post

I have this simple code:

```
function dlgEditPhase_okClicked(dlgEditPhase, event) {
    $.post("/overview/phase/"+dlgEditPhase.projectId, 
        JSON.stringify({
            "phaseName": dlgEditPhase.phaseName,
            "begin": dlgEditPhase.begin,
            "end": dlgEditPhase.end
        }),
        function(data) {
            dlgEditPhase.close();
            location.reload();
        },
        "json"
    ).fail(function(data) {
        alert(data.responseJSON);
    });
}
```

Problem is, the `fail` is always fired, even when the POST call returns code 200 or 202.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you post a response example? fail can also fire because response is not a valid json

Comment: @scaff that was it. If you make it an answer, I can accept. (My response was empty, which is invalid JSON)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fail can also fire because response is not a valid json